# How to bind textBox to SelectedItem of DataGrid bound to a DataTable

Tags: mysql, wpf, data-binding

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="ImportsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  />
```

That is bound to a DataTable created from a MySQL select like so:

```
string sqlString = "select * from import;";
MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, _sqlConn);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
da.Fill(dataTable);
ImportsGrid.DataContext = dataTable;
```

Then I have some textboxes in the window that I want to bind to the SelectedItem of this DataGrid so that the values from the DataGrid selection appear in the TextBoxes.

Is there a way to do this? All the examples that I saw doing this worked by creating an object for each row of the DataGrid, storing those objects in a list and setting that list as an ItemsSource of the DataGrid, then binding to the SelectedItem.

Comment: You have the names or indexes of the columns in the table.
The SelectedItem will have a DataRowView instance.
Adding an index (number or name of a column) to it - get the value of the corresponding cell of this row of the table.

Comment: @EldHasp Thanks! That works. It didn't occur to me that I could put the index into the binding path for some reason.